# Table of file names with special characters

Tags: tables, tabularx, urls

For my thesis, I want to create a list/table with the file paths of all data I show in my figures.
What I came up so far is a combination of `tabularx` and `longtable` (via `ltxtable`), and putting the path of the files into the `\path` command of `hyperref`. Unfortunately, neither `\path` nor `\url` are able to cope with special characters like `ä,ö,ü,µ` that can be present in the file names. `\path{blaµ}` inserts broken characters while `\url{blaµ}` doesn't compile at all.

In total, I have ~200 very long file names. How could I obtain a proper list?

Bonus question: Is there any nicer way to make the table wider than the print area instead of the ugly `1.2\textwidth` (which ofc raises an overfull hbox)? For my other tables I used the `\centerfloat` command of `memoir`, but this doesn't work for the non-floating longtable.

My MnWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,ngerman]{memoir}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{varioref}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{ltxtable}
\usepackage[nameinlink]{cleveref}

\addto\captionsngerman{ 
\def\figurename{Abb.}
}


\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image-a}
\caption{my figure}
\label{fig:a}
\end{figure}

\LTXtable{1.2\textwidth}{filelist.tex}

\end{document}
```

The content of `filelist.tex`:

```
begin{longtable}{@{}llX@{}}
\caption{List of data files}\\
Fig. & Details & Path \\\midrule
\cref{fig:a} & bla bla & \path{Curry-Charakterisierung/Abbildungsverhältnis/20190402_b_Ne_0,5mMC_KPF_3D_1s_sort.dat} \\ 
\end{longtable}
```

The result:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

This allows breaking just at `/`

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,ngerman]{memoir}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{varioref}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{ltxtable}
\usepackage[nameinlink]{cleveref}

\addto\captionsngerman{ 
\def\figurename{Abb.}
}

\catcode`\/=\active
\newcommand\pathsetting{%
\raggedright
\arraybackslash
\catcode`\/=\active
\catcode`\_=12
\let/=\slash
}
\catcode`\/=12


\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image-a}
\caption{my figure}
\label{fig:a}
\end{figure}

\noindent X\dotfill X

\noindent\hspace*{-.1\textwidth}X\dotfill X\hspace*{-.1\textwidth}\mbox{}

\setlength\LTleft{-.1\textwidth}
\setlength\LTright{-.1\textwidth}
\LTXtable{1\textwidth}{filelist.tex}

\end{document}
```

---

```
\begin{longtable}{
@{}
ll
>{\pathsetting}X
@{}}
\caption{List of data files}\\
Fig. & Details & Path \\\midrule
\cref{fig:a} & bla bla & \texttt{Curry-Charakterisierung/Abbildungsverhältnis/20190402_b_Ne_0,5mMC_KPF_3D_1s_sort.dat} \\ 
\end{longtable}
```

If you want to also allow breaking after `_` you could adjust to

```
\catcode`\/=\active
\catcode`\_=\active
\newcommand\pathsetting{%
\raggedright
\arraybackslash
\catcode`\/=\active
\catcode`\_=\active
\let/=\slash
\def_{\string_\linebreak[0]}%
}
\catcode`\/=12
\catcode`\_=8
```

Comment: Is it possible to allow line breaks at more characters (or even all)? The longest string I found in my list is `Methoxyethanol/Corrected/2019_03/20190327_a_MeOEtOH_-15C_1,8bar_He_0,7bar_1mm_DRT_lam90_KPF_0,5m_100µm_M320,0_10min_cal.dat` which doesn't fit onto the page with this approach.

Comment: yes it would be trivial to allow breaking at  `_` for example, allowing breaking at normal letters without messing up the UTF-8 decoding must be possible but a bit more challenging (unless a package already does it,which is possible of course)

Comment: @Eldrad I added a version for breaking at `_`

Comment: I guess this is one where we want Enrico's `\text_map_function:nN` idea ...

Comment: @JosephWright or luatex:-)